# conda install python-graphviz: stuck at Solving environment

Tags: graphviz, anaconda3

When I tried to `conda install python-graphviz` in Anaconda3 on my Ubuntu machine, it stuck at `Solving environment`:

```
(base) $ conda install python-graphviz
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: /
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Tried `conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz` or `conda install -c anaconda python-graphviz` yet ?

Comment: No luck. Still stuck as `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve`

Comment: None of the two installation methods worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. The following was my solution:

Install graphviz manually.

E.g. for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install graphviz graphviz-dev
```

Then do a pip install for the python package.

```
pip install graphviz
```

Confusingly the pip install of graphviz is the same as the conda install of python-graphviz. (bad naming)

Typing this from my phone so better double check my commands for typos. Let me know if that solved it.

Comment: I think they have solved the problem. I can install graphviz using the command "conda install python-graphviz" command. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Oops, it stucks again on another machine. Problem not completely solved yet.